# spring cloud sleuth cannot geerate spanID

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-logback

it is necessary to generate a span-id for all that gets into the console log, but unfortunately the span-id is not generated:

```
2019-03-13 12:35:27.116  INFO [core.data,,,] 13304 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1fd386c3: startup date [Wed Mar 13 12:35:27 MSK 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-03-13 12:35:27.268  INFO [core.data,,,] 13304 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-03-13 12:35:27.298  INFO [core.data,,,] 13304 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66207a2f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2019-03-13 14:58:43,737+0300 p=INFO l=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean trace-id= span-id= Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-03-13 14:58:43,737+0300 p=INFO l=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean trace-id= span-id= Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2019-03-13 14:58:43,738+0300 p=INFO l=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean trace-id= span-id= Mapping filter: 'unauthorizedLogbookFilter' to: [/*]
```

**application.yml**

```
    logging:
      config: classpath:config/logging/logback.xml
    pattern:
      console: '%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ"} %clr(p=%level) %clr(t=%t){yellow} %clr(l=%logger){magenta} %clr(trace-id=%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}){blue} %clr(span-id=%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}){cyan} %msg%n'

      level:
        org.hibernate: info
        org.springframework: info
```

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--spring defaults-->
  <include 
    resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console- 
appender.xml"/>
<!--custom configurations-->
<include resource="config/logging/file-appender.xml"/>

<!-- level configurations-->
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

span-id generation occurs for an explicitly called logging method:

```
Logger log = loggerFactory().getLogger(this.class);
public void method(){ log.info("test"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

First create an Rest Api and make an api request to it, if not already done.
If you are using Restemplate try creating a RestTemplate bean.

Also set the logging level to debug

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to generate a span-id for all that gets into the console log. Hit your API's then you can see the **span-id**  and **trace-id** in your logs in console.

Comment: and in what situations it then generates span-id and trace-id

Comment: edited console output and file application.yml. and everywhere span-id= and trace-id= are empty

Comment: its for tracing processes, or ingress/egress to your application i.e. hit an API